Recursive CTE for leave accrual projections
I have two tables

Leave_policy:




Leave_Type_Id
Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural
Months Until
Annual_Max_CarryOver




LT1
3
0
72


LT1
5
24
120


LT2
4
0
96


LT2
6
24
144




Empl_Leave:




EMP_ID
LEAVE_BALANCE
Leave_Type_ID
Hire_date
Last_Accrual_Date




701
68
LT2
10/1/2002
7/27/2024


702
85
LT1
11/12/1996
7/27/2024


703
230
LT3
9/8/2007
7/27/2024


704
129
LT1
3/4/2012
7/27/2024


705
187.5
LT2
6/1/2008
7/27/2024



My goal is get employee leave projections (Current leave balance + LeaveRate * Number of Accruals) for the next six months from last accrual date and also leave projections to employee hire anniversary.
Something like this:



Empl_ID
Current_Balance
For next six Month balance
For Until Employee Hire Anniversary




701
68
(68+Running total until 6 months)
(68 + Running total until Hire anniversary date)


702
85
(85+RunningTotal until 6 months)
(85+Running total until Hire anniversary date)



Employee have bi-weekly leave accruals as only two per month, Months_until and LeaveType_Id columns define how much Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accrual will be as in the first table. Months_Until is a tenure period MONTH diff between Leave Accrual Date and Hire_Date.
In between these calculations I have to follow Annual_Max_Carryover if the date crosses next year. I am on SQL 2019.
I tried with a recursive CTE.

So, every month one should deduct from Current_balance what, Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural * 2? and if balance is > Annual_Max_CarryOver then balance should be adjusted to Annual_Max_CarryOver when the year passes? How does From_month control things?

"some calculated value" doesn't explain anything. Don't forget, we can't see your specs, nor read your mind. You need to give us all the information to be able to answer your question. That means giving sample data and expected results and explicit definitions of the logic you need; not vague requirements.

@siggemannen , I apologize i forgot to add that info in the question , i made edit to the question now with all the details , Every pay period Leave accrual happens and the balance gets appended , Current balance + Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural . Yes if the target date is crossing the Year then all the current balance will reset to Max_Carry_Over balance and gets appended with Leave rate for the rest of the pay periods until the target date

@ThomA, Sorry , I did not put the details properly , I just updated the question with proper details , Yes I mean to say running total .

Months_Until is a tenure period MONTH diff between Accrual Date and accrual Date. - possible ... and Hire date?

@ValNik - I think i entered the Accrual date wrong in that table - Accrual date is same for all employees 07-27 . Also for ""Months_Until is a tenure period MONTH diff between Accrual Date and accrual Date"" Yes sir - thats typo - Yes its diff netween Accrual dates and hire date

For Last_Accrual_date 2024-07-27 what is next 6 Accrual dates? If every 2 week then 2024-07-27-0, 2024-08-03(1),2024-08-10(2), 2024-08-17(3), 2024-08-24(4), 2024-08-31(5), 2024-09-07(6) .

@ValNik - I am looking for projections for next 6 months from 07-27 , So it would be every Accrual from 07-27 for every two weeks but limiting only two per month , So what ever accruals that occurs between 07-27 through 01-27-2025

See (https://dbfiddle.uk/oLvdmBFY). There 3 accruals in November( if calculate every 2 week).

@ValNik Yes sir - but i should take only first two accruals in a month as there is a limit -

Pls, edit question and add correct Last_accrual_date, point about 2 accruals limit in moth. And From_months compared with (Accrual_date-Hire_date).

@ValNik - I updated the question now. Sorry about that

I found the task interesting and quite difficult. Please (vote to)reopen the question for answers. The intended solution in the example (https://dbfiddle.uk/BmelfWkU)

Please read [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Example for SQL Server 2019 (https://dbfiddle.uk/dKmce3nE)

See example:
I will create Accrual calendar. This calendar table can be created separately as a temporary or permanent table, with corresponding indexes. Especially if such calculations are regular.  This will simplify the query and improve performance.
Test data. Added LT3 and users 905,906 for test Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural,From_Months and  Annual_Max_CarryOver changes.
create table Leave_policy(Leave_Type_Id varchar(3), Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural int
     ,From_Months int,  Annual_Max_CarryOver int);
insert into Leave_policy values
 ('LT1',    3,  0,  72)
,('LT1',    5,  24, 120)
,('LT2',    4,  0,  96)
,('LT2',    6,  24, 144)
,('LT3',    1,  0,  96)
,('LT3',    2,  24, 144)
,('LT3',    3,  28, 144)
,('LT3',    4,  32, 144)
,('LT3',    5,  36, 144)
;
create table Empl_Leave(id int identity,EMP_ID int, LEAVE_BALANCE float, Leave_Type_ID varchar(3)
     ,Hire_date date,   Last_Accrual_Date date);
insert into Empl_leave(emp_id,leave_balance,Leave_type_id,Hire_date,Last_Accrual_date) values
 (701,  68,     'LT2','10/1/2002','7/27/2024')
,(905,  110,    'LT2','11/2/2022','7/27/2024')
,(906,  110,    'LT3','05/3/2022','7/27/2024')
;




Leave_Type_Id
Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural
From_Months
Annual_Max_CarryOver




LT1
3
0
72


LT1
5
24
120


LT2
4
0
96


LT2
6
24
144


LT3
1
0
96


LT3
2
24
144


LT3
3
28
144


LT3
4
32
144


LT3
5
36
144






id
EMP_ID
LEAVE_BALANCE
Leave_Type_ID
Hire_date
Last_Accrual_Date




1
701
68
LT2
2002-10-01
2024-07-27


2
905
110
LT2
2022-11-02
2024-07-27


3
906
110
LT3
2022-05-03
2024-07-27



Query
-- version for SQL Server 2019
-- generate series replaced by recursive series generator
-- and greates(...) by case when ...
with params as( -- query parameters
  select startDt  -- calculation start date
    ,datefromparts(year(startDt)+1,1,1) nyDt  -- next new year
    ,dateadd(month,6,startDt) projDt  -- projection date 6 month after startDt
  from (select max(Last_accrual_date) startDt from Empl_Leave) sDt
)
,series as (
      select dateadd(week,2,startDt) Nad -- Next_accrual_date
          ,dateadd(week,26*2,startDt) endDt
      from params
      union all
      select dateadd(week,2,r.Nad) Nad, endDt
      from series r
      where r.Nad<=endDt
)
,AccrualCalendar as( -- Accrual calendar to year
select Nad  -- Next accrual dates in calendar
from(
  select *,row_number()over(partition by year(Nad),month(Nad) order by Nad)rn
  from series 
    -- (
    --   select dateadd(week,n*2,startDt) Nad -- Next_accrual_date
    --   from  (select value n from generate_series(1,26)) wn
    --  cross apply params
    --  )a
  )b
  where rn<=2 -- take only 2 date for every months
)
,lp as( -- Leave_policy with To_Months
  select *,lead(From_months,1,999999)
             over(partition by Leave_Type_Id order by From_months)-1 To_Months
  from Leave_policy
)

main part
,empDates as( -- employee params and dates, including next hire Anniversary
select *
  ,case when nyDt>projDt then
    case when nyDt>haDt then 
      case when haDt>projDt then haDt else projDt end
    else haDt end
   else 
    case when projDt>haDt then projDt else haDt end 
   end lastDt
from(
select id,EMP_ID,LEAVE_BALANCE lb,  Leave_Type_ID lt, Hire_date hdt
  , startDt,nyDt,projDt
  ,case when datefromparts(year(startDt),month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))<startDt
       then datefromparts(year(startDt)+1,month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))
   else datefromparts(year(startDt),month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))
   end haDt -- next hire Anniversary
from Empl_Leave el
cross apply params
  )t
)
,allEmpDates as( -- all dates for employee -- accrual,next hire Anniversary
  -- new year,projection
 -- Accruals
select ed.*,'ac' as sk,Nad as pointDt,datediff(month,hDt,Nad) pointM
from empDates ed
left join AccrualCalendar ac on Nad between startDt and lastDt -- greatest(haDt,nyDt,projDt)
  -- Control points
union all
select * 
  ,case when sk='ny'then nyDt 
          when sk='proj'then projDt
          when sk='ha'then haDt 
     end pointDt
  ,datediff(month,hDt,case when sk='ny'then nyDt 
          when sk='proj'then projDt
          when sk='ha'then haDt 
     end) pointM
from  empDates
left join (values('ha'),('ny'),('proj'))t(sk)
     on sk in('ha','proj')
         or (sk='ny' and projDt>=nyDt)
  )
,balance1 as(-- rolling sum - balance for every date
select ad.* 
  ,sum(case when sk='ac' then Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural else 0 end)
    over(partition by emp_id order by pointDt)
  +lb currentB
  ,case when sk='ac' then Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural else 0 end leaveQty
  ,From_Months,To_Months,Annual_Max_CarryOver maxCarry
from allEmpDates  ad
left join lp on lp.Leave_Type_id=ad.lt
  and lp.From_Months<=pointM and lp.To_Months>=pointM
)
,AccrualsNYover as( -- correction for max carry - Annual_Max_CarryOver
select  *
  ,case when sk='ny' and currentB>maxCarry then maxCarry-currentB
   else 0 end newyearCorrection
from balance1
)
,balance2 as( -- rolling balance with correction (max carry over)
select *
from(
select * 
  ,sum(case when sk='ac' then leaveQty else 0 end
       +case when sk='ny' then newyearCorrection else 0 end)
    over(partition by emp_id order by pointDt) 
  +lb as CurrentBalance
from AccrualsNYover
)t 
 where sk in('ny','ha','proj') -- after balance calculation take only Control points
)
select EMP_ID,min(lt) Leave_type_id,min(hdt)HireDate
  ,min(startDt) Last_Accrual_date,min(lb) Leave_balance
  ,max(case when sk='proj' then CurrentBalance end) projBalance
  ,max(case when sk='ha' then CurrentBalance end) Hire_Anniversary_Balance
  ,max(case when sk='ny' then CurrentBalance end) CarryOver_Balance
 ,max(nyDt)NewYearDt,max(projDt)ProjectionDate,max(haDt)Hire_Anniversary_date
from balance2
group by emp_id
order by emp_id 




EMP_ID
Leave_type_id
HireDate
Last_Accrual_date
Leave_balance
projBalance
Hire_Anniversary_Balance
CarryOver_Balance
NewYearDt
ProjectionDate
Hire_Anniversary_date




701
LT2
2002-10-01
2024-07-27
68
140
92
128
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01


905
LT2
2022-11-02
2024-07-27
110
156
140
144
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02


906
LT3
2022-05-03
2024-07-27
110
146
175
138
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03



Query for 2022
-- version for SQL Server 2022
with params as( -- query parameters
  select startDt  -- calculation start date
    ,datefromparts(year(startDt)+1,1,1) nyDt  -- next new year
    ,dateadd(month,6,startDt) projDt  -- projection date 6 month after startDt
  from (select max(Last_accrual_date) startDt from Empl_Leave) sDt
)
,AccrualCalendar as( -- Accrual calendar to year
select Nad  -- Next accrual dates in calendar
from(
  select *,row_number()over(partition by year(Nad),month(Nad) order by Nad)rn
  from(
      select dateadd(week,n*2,startDt) Nad -- Next_accrual_date
      from  (select value n from generate_series(1,26)) wn
      cross apply params
     )a
  )b
  where rn<=2 -- take only 2 date for every months
)
,lp as( -- Leave_policy with To_Months
  select *,lead(From_months,1,999999)
             over(partition by Leave_Type_Id order by From_months)-1 To_Months
  from Leave_policy
)
,empDates as( -- employee params and dates, including next hire Anniversary
select id,EMP_ID,LEAVE_BALANCE lb,  Leave_Type_ID lt, Hire_date hdt
  , startDt,nyDt,projDt
  ,case when datefromparts(year(startDt),month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))<startDt
       then datefromparts(year(startDt)+1,month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))
   else datefromparts(year(startDt),month(Hire_date),day(Hire_date))
   end haDt -- next hire Anniversary
from Empl_Leave el
cross apply params
  )
,allEmpDates as( -- all dates for employee -- accrual,next hire Anniversary
  -- new year,projection
select ed.*,'ac' as sk,Nad as pointDt,datediff(month,hDt,Nad) pointM
from empDates ed
left join AccrualCalendar ac on Nad between startDt and greatest(haDt,nyDt,projDt)
union all
select * 
  ,case when sk='ny'then nyDt 
          when sk='proj'then projDt
          when sk='ha'then haDt 
     end pointDt
  ,datediff(month,hDt,case when sk='ny'then nyDt 
          when sk='proj'then projDt
          when sk='ha'then haDt 
     end) pointM
from  empDates
left join (values('ha'),('ny'),('proj'))t(sk)
     on sk in('ha','proj')
         or (sk='ny' and projDt>=nyDt)
  )
,balance1 as(-- rolling sum - balance for every date
select ad.* 
  ,sum(case when sk='ac' then Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural else 0 end)
    over(partition by emp_id order by pointDt)
  +lb currentB
  ,case when sk='ac' then Leave_Rate_Per_Every_Accural else 0 end leaveQty
  ,From_Months,To_Months,Annual_Max_CarryOver maxCarry
from allEmpDates  ad
left join lp on lp.Leave_Type_id=ad.lt
  and lp.From_Months<=pointM and lp.To_Months>=pointM
)
,AccrualsNYover as( -- correction for max carry - Annual_Max_CarryOver
select  *
  ,case when sk='ny' and currentB>maxCarry then maxCarry-currentB
   else 0 end newyearCorrection
from balance1
)
,balance2 as( -- rolling balance with correction (max carry over)
select *
from(
select * 
  ,sum(case when sk='ac' then leaveQty else 0 end
       +case when sk='ny' then newyearCorrection else 0 end)
    over(partition by emp_id order by pointDt) 
  +lb as CurrentBalance
from AccrualsNYover
)t 
where sk in('ny','ha','proj')
)
select EMP_ID,min(lt) Leave_type_id,min(hdt)HireDate
  ,min(startDt) Last_Accrual_date,min(lb) Leave_balance
  ,max(case when sk='proj' then CurrentBalance end) projBalance
  ,max(case when sk='ha' then CurrentBalance end) Hire_Anniversary_Balance
  ,max(case when sk='ny' then CurrentBalance end) CarryOver_Balance
  ,max(nyDt)NewYearDt,max(projDt)ProjectionDate,max(haDt)Hire_Anniversary_date
from balance2
group by emp_id
order by emp_id 

Output before grouping



EMP_ID
lb
lt
sk
pointDt
currentB
leaveQty
maxCarry
newyearCorrection
CurrentBalance
startDt
hdt
nyDt
projDt
haDt
lastDt
pointM
From_Months
To_Months




701
68
LT2
ac
2024-08-10
74
6
144
0
74
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
262
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-08-24
80
6
144
0
80
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
262
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-09-07
86
6
144
0
86
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
263
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-09-21
92
6
144
0
92
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
263
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ha
2024-10-01
92
0
144
0
92
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
264
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-10-05
98
6
144
0
98
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
264
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-10-19
104
6
144
0
104
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
264
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-11-02
110
6
144
0
110
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
265
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-11-16
116
6
144
0
116
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
265
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-12-14
122
6
144
0
122
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
266
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2024-12-28
128
6
144
0
128
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
266
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ny
2025-01-01
128
0
144
0
128
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
267
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2025-01-11
134
6
144
0
134
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
267
24
999998


701
68
LT2
ac
2025-01-25
140
6
144
0
140
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
267
24
999998


701
68
LT2
proj
2025-01-27
140
0
144
0
140
2024-07-27
2002-10-01
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-10-01
2025-01-27
267
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-08-10
114
4
96
0
114
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
21
0
23


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-08-24
118
4
96
0
118
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
21
0
23


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-09-07
122
4
96
0
122
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
22
0
23


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-09-21
126
4
96
0
126
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
22
0
23


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-10-05
130
4
96
0
130
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
23
0
23


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-10-19
134
4
96
0
134
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
23
0
23


905
110
LT2
ha
2024-11-02
140
0
144
0
140
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
24
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-11-02
140
6
144
0
140
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
24
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-11-16
146
6
144
0
146
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
24
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-12-14
152
6
144
0
152
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
25
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2024-12-28
158
6
144
0
158
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
25
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ny
2025-01-01
158
0
144
-14
144
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
26
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2025-01-11
164
6
144
0
150
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
26
24
999998


905
110
LT2
ac
2025-01-25
170
6
144
0
156
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
26
24
999998


905
110
LT2
proj
2025-01-27
170
0
144
0
156
2024-07-27
2022-11-02
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2024-11-02
2025-01-27
26
24
999998


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-08-10
112
2
144
0
112
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
27
24
27


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-08-24
114
2
144
0
114
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
27
24
27


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-09-07
117
3
144
0
117
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
28
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-09-21
120
3
144
0
120
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
28
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-10-05
123
3
144
0
123
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
29
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-10-19
126
3
144
0
126
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
29
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-11-02
129
3
144
0
129
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
30
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-11-16
132
3
144
0
132
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
30
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-12-14
135
3
144
0
135
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
31
28
31


906
110
LT3
ac
2024-12-28
138
3
144
0
138
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
31
28
31


906
110
LT3
ny
2025-01-01
138
0
144
0
138
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
32
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-01-11
142
4
144
0
142
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
32
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-01-25
146
4
144
0
146
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
32
32
35


906
110
LT3
proj
2025-01-27
146
0
144
0
146
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
32
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-02-08
150
4
144
0
150
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
33
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-02-22
154
4
144
0
154
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
33
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-03-08
158
4
144
0
158
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
34
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-03-22
162
4
144
0
162
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
34
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-04-05
166
4
144
0
166
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
35
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-04-19
170
4
144
0
170
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
35
32
35


906
110
LT3
ac
2025-05-03
175
5
144
0
175
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
36
36
999998


906
110
LT3
ha
2025-05-03
175
0
144
0
175
2024-07-27
2022-05-03
2025-01-01
2025-01-27
2025-05-03
2025-05-03
36
36
999998



fiddle
The case has not been verified when the new year and the date of accruals coincide.

@VaiNik Thank you so much . I cant thank you enough.. "Amazing" in one word.
Is there a way to change Annual_Max_CarryOver to happen on Employee Hire Anniversary instead on New year 1st ? Just checking.
